# Dynamically calculate padding-left

Tags: javascript

Here's a sample division:

```
<div style="padding:0 0 0 30px; background:url(http://www.google.com/help/hc/images/sidewiki_157505_comment_bubble.gif) left center no-repeat;">some text</div>
```

I wonder how I can calculate the padding-left:30px dynamically so that any icon I choose the padding-left value changes according to the image width.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would use [jQuery](http://jquery.org):

```
$('div#id').css('padding-left');
```

You would need to have a way to select the DIV, hence my artificial `#id`.

Examples: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/LvPH6/1/